# Hartshorne Exercise V 1.12: the numerical equivalence doesn't preserve very-ampleness.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a projective irreducible nonsingular surface over an algebraically closed field $k$, the exercise asks us to give an example of $X$ and two numerically equivalent divisors $D$ and $D'$ such that $D$ is very ample while $D'$ is not.

Could you provide an example (hints are also welcome)? I have no idea, since I'm not familiar with numerical equivalence and I haven't handled many examples.

Comment: Do you know such an example for curves? If you do, you can take products to get higher dimensional examples.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks for replying. We don't have intersection theory on curves, hence numerical equivalence is not well defined on curves. What do you mean by "examples on curves"?

Comment: I think what Mohan is alluding to is that two divisors on a curve can be thought of as numerically equivalent if they have the same degree. Do you know an example of a very ample divisor $A$ on a curve $C$ such that there is another divisor $D$ with $\deg A = \deg D$, but $D$ is not very ample?

Comment: @TabesBridges thanks, I have found the example.